# I have api objectfield name, how can I get the label?

Tags: visualforce, dynamic-visualforce

Im working in a site, And I need to present many fields to be filled and the page, so accoding to a selecction before, I have all the field but I have the Api Name, and the object name, but, With this api object field name, how can I get the label????

Example. I have "Student__c", I need to present "Student" to the user.

Thanks a lot for ur help!

---

Ok, thanks for ur answuers but I think I did not explain well this situation.

I have a list of string, where I have the information but in Api's name. 
I present this fields in a table, so the user is filling the fields but with an inputText and not with an inputfield!.. So, in this moment, I dont know what is the label of each field.

My question basically, if by means of a query I could know the label of a field, if I know the api field name and the object name..
My question is if there is a way to consult this info!...

I know if I have the object is enough using an inputfield, But I cant do that. Neither set the label with HTML directly 'cause this is something dynamic.

Anyone knows how can I know, or consult, I guess by means of a query, how to get this label names???

Comment: Are you creating a **Visualforce** page?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure if you can do it in pure visualforce. With Apex controller you'll be able to do something like this:

```
String objectName = 'Contact';
String fieldName = 'FirstName';

List<Schema.DescribeSObjectResult> describeSobjectsResult = Schema.describeSObjects(new List<String>{objectName}); // this can accept list of strings, we describe only one object here
System.debug(describeSobjectsResult);
String objectLabel = describeSobjectsResult[0].getLabel();
Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> allFields = describeSobjectsResult[0].fields.getMap();
System.debug(allFields);
String fieldLabel = allFields.get(fieldName).getDescribe().getLabel();

System.debug(objectName + '.' + fieldName + '  => ' + objectLabel + ', ' + fieldLabel);
```

Totally dynamic retrieval of object label & field label ;)

See http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dynamic_describe_objects_understanding.htm for more goodies.
Maybe it'd be possible in pure Visualforce with the `['string here']` syntax...

Also... exactly how dynamic you'll have to be? Check out the fieldsets in VF developer guide, might simplify your page greatly...

Comment: Not sure why this got downvoted, but this is the best way to do this. Anything else relies on hardcoding the label in code instead of referencing the metadata.

Comment: Hi @MichaelWelburn, thx for the kind words :) No idea really. We don't know how dynamic the solution has to be. If the fields point to some fields on some sObject(s) - I see only my way. If there is a concrete `Account` etc. somewhere in the controller - I like sfdcfox's way as it feels cleaner and closer to fieldsets solution.

Comment: This is the real answer I was looking for!... So Thank you. I figure it out from another website, but its your same answer...

Answer (score 15):

Use $ObjectType global variable, and it could print the Student__c field label like this(please change the object name as needed)

```
<apex:outputLabel value="{!$ObjectType.CustomObject__c.fields.Student__c.Label}" />
```

Answer (score 4):

You can generate labels dynamically:

### Controller

```
public with sharing class dyno {
    public Account account { get; set; }
    public String[] fields { get; set; }
    { account = new Account();
      fields = new String[] { 'Name','Industry' };
      }
}
```

### Page

```
<apex:page controller="dyno">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!fields}" var="field">
                <apex:column value="{!$ObjectType.Account.fields[field].Label}"/>
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:inputText value="{!account[field]}"/>
                </apex:column>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 4):

another simple way to display field label from apex, is like this (if the object and field is not to be dynamic) :

```
 Schema.SObjectType.Contact.fields.Student__c.getLabel()
```

If it is to be displayed on vf, then you can use the following code :

```
<apex:outputText value="{!$ObjectType.Contact.fields.Student__c.Label}"/>
```

Comment: The nice thing about using the `Schema` approach is that it checks that the field exists at compile time. If you use a `Map` you could get a runtime exception.

Answer (score 3):

An example of using the `label` attribute in a simple Visualforce Controller:

```
<apex:page standardController="My_Custom_Object__c" >
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock title="My Section Title">
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2" title="Section Header">
                <apex:inputField value="{!My_Custom_Object__c.Student__c}" label="Student"/>
            <apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Another more general example:

```
<apex:page standardController="My_Custom_Object__c" >
    <style>
        .myLabel{
            margin-right:20px;
        }
    </style> 
    <apex:form>
        <apex:outputText value="Student" styleClass="myLabel"/><apex:inputField value="{!My_Custom_Object__c.Student__c}"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you have is a string, here's another simple solution:

```
String objectName = 'CustomObject__c';

Schema.SObjectType sObjectType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objectName);
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult describeSobjectsResult = sObjectType.getDescribe();
String objectLabel = describeSobjectsResult.getLabel();

System.debug(objectLabel);
```