# I need the label of a Field, I have Api's objectfield Name

Tags: apex

In my controller I have a List of string. This list contains The Object Name, and the Field Name. So, I need to get the "Label" Name of this fields.

I need to make a query where the conditions is the object name and the fieldname.

Please take consideration that this is Dynamic, So, I cant just simply create a list of the object because in this list of string I may have any object of the whole solution.

So, I dont know how to make this query to the metadata, in order to know the labels name of my list string of fields. Example:

I have "Student__c" in a variable, I need to get "Student" in another variable. but it gotta be the "real" label of the respective object.

and it can be a plenty of fields, so cant not be hardcore. It have to be consulting in somewhere the correct label, but I dont know where to consult. I'll really appreciate your help!

Comment: Have you actually tried any of the answers from http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/i-have-api-objectfield-name-how-can-i-get-the-label ?

Answer (score 15):

Have you looked into [Dynamic Apex](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dynamic_describe_objects_understanding.htm)? If you know the Object API Name, you can retrieve it via a Describe call, and then access the fields using the [fields](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_Schema_DescribeSObjectResult_instance_methods.htm) method, which allows you get access the field names as keys from a getMap() call.

The following isn't the most efficient for reuse, but you should be able to glean what methods you'll need to leverage.

> Schema.[getGlobalDescribe()](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_System_Schema_getGlobalDescribe.htm).get('ObjectName').[getDescribe()](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_Schema_DescribeSObjectResult_instance_methods.htm).[fields](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_Schema_DescribeSObjectResult_fields.htm).getMap().get('FieldName').[getDescribe()](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_Schema_DescribeFieldResult_instance_methods.htm).getLabel();

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you know the name of the object and the field (I would presume so!), you can use this directly in Visualforce:

```
{!$ObjectType[objectName].fields[fieldName].Label}
```

Comment: would this work like this: `<apex:outputLabel value="{!$ObjectType.Request_for_System_Change__c.fields.Any_additional_comments_Data_Request__c.Label}+':'"/>` for my object **Request_for_System_Change__c** and the field called *Any_additional_comments_Data_Request__c*

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer I was looking for!

```
   String type= 'MyCustomObject__c';  // Say,this is my object
   Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> schemaMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
    Schema.SObjectType leadSchema = schemaMap.get(type);
    Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = leadSchema.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
    for (String fieldName: fieldMap.keySet()) {  
        String mylabel;
          //It provides to get the object fields label.
         mylabel = fieldMap.get(fieldName).getDescribe().getLabel();
   }
```

Comment: Eh. So you really didn't actually bother to check the answers from your old question? I've posted pretty much same thing for you: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/22775. At least please mark your answer as accepted so it goes "off the radar".