# How to get Object Label

Tags: sobject, schema

I have object's API Name

How can I get Object's Label ?

I am trying this

```
Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> schemaMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();

Schema.SObjectType schemaObj = schemaMap.get(SObjApiName);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can retrieve label of given object like this:

```
String objectName = 'Contact';

List<Schema.DescribeSObjectResult> describeSobjectsResult = Schema.describeSObjects(new List<String>{objectName}); // this can accept list of strings, we describe only one object here
String objectLabel = describeSobjectsResult[0].getLabel();
```

[Reference](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/i-have-api-objectfield-name-how-can-i-get-the-label)

Answer (score 1):

```
    String type = 'Account';

    Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> schemaMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
    Schema.SObjectType leadSchema = schemaMap.get(type);
    Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = leadSchema.getDescribe().fields.getMap();

    //to get single field label in account
    fieldMap.get(field_Name__c).getDescribe().getLabel()

    //to get all field labels
    for (String fieldName: fieldMap.keySet()) {
      // list of all field API name
      System.debug('-->Field API Name='+fieldName);

      //It provides to get the object fields label.
      AllLabels.add(fieldMap.get(fieldName).getDescribe().getLabel());
    }
```

Comment: I guess Yogesh is asking for label of object and not fields.

Comment: oh yea, i missed that! oops

Answer (score 0):

Just try this code if you want to retrive the object name from a string in visualforce page.

```
public string selectedobject{get;set;}
public sObject sObj{get;set;} 
Map m  = Schema.getGlobalDescribe() ;  
Schema.SObjectType s = m.get(selectedobject) ;    
sObj =s.newSObject();
```